# I am getting jQuery [object Object] error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, dom

Hi I getting frustrated with this [object Object] thing.  I have googled for quite a while today, and haven't found anything to solve my thing. 
this the part of the code that is returning this `[object Object]`

Thank you very much for your answer, time and consideration. :)

Comment: How do we get that _thing_ ?

Comment: @Rayon what do you mean?

Comment: When do you get `[object Object]` ? How do we execute your code ? Where is your HTML ?

Comment: I am confused with your syntax:why not have...var lName = $("#notPat_lname").val();...

Comment: @Rayon I am getting this [object Object] after I click the back button.

Comment: @gavgrif because i have a patient 1 and patient 2 tabs that's why.

Comment: var patient2_lName = $("#patient2 #notPat_lname").val();... remember ids MUST be unique so you need to target he patient 2 individual forms fields using their id's

Comment: @gavgrif I have tried your suggestion. But still i didn't work.

Comment: Out of all this code, which lines **specifically** are giving you `[object Object]`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox i think the <pre>parent.top.$('#patient1').contents().find("#notPat_lname").val(lName);
                            parent.top.$('#patient1').contents().find("#notPat_fname").val(fName);
                            parent.top.$('#patient1').contents().find("#notPat_mname").val(mName);<code>

Comment: Why are you passing `val` an argument? "This method does not accept any arguments." - From the jQuery docs. Can you use `console.log()` to show us the actual output of these lines.

Answer (score 0):

When you call [`.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) with an argument, it returns a jQuery object. Your variables (lname, fname, mname) are objects. When you try to set the value of an element to an object, JavaScript will automatically convert it to a string.

alert() also requires a string, so giving it an object produces the same result.

```
alert({})
```